# Devise login form not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a login form (using devise for user authentication) that looks like so:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => {:class=>"wrap center"}) do |f| %>
     <%=f.text_field :email, :placeholder => 'Email', :name => "email"%>
     <%=f.password_field :password, :placeholder => 'Password', :name => "pwd"%>
    <div class="txt-right">
      <a href="#" class="forgot"><i>Forgot your password?</i></a>
    </div>
    <%if @host != 'localhost'%>
      <%=f.submit 'LOGIN', :class => 'button', :onclick =>"_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Retention', 'Login']);"%>
    <%else%>
      <%=f.submit 'LOGIN', :class => 'button'%>
    <%end%>
  <%end%>
```

This form was originally in a file in views/users where it worked find, and now I'm using it in views/home and every time I hit submit instead of logging me in it redirects me to /users/sign_in (the default sign in page devise gives you) even with the correct log in info. I double checked, and my application helper does contain:

```
      def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the name declaration in your form.

```
<%=f.text_field :email, :placeholder => 'Email' %>
<%=f.password_field :password, :placeholder => 'Password' %>
```